# Can I override a parent interface method in a child interface in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation

I have an interface hierarchy that I'm trying to document using proper .net xml comments. I have a method shared by all interfaces in the hierarchy, which I declare at the top level, that I would like to give a more specific comment for on the sub-interfaces.

In other words, something like this:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    /// <summary>Returns a string often spoken by this animal.</summary>
    string speak();
}

public interface IDog : IAnimal
{
    /// <summary>Returns a string representation of some barking noise.</summary>
    string speak();
}

public interface IDuck : IAnimal
{
    /// <summary>Returns a string representation of some quacking noise.</summary>
    string speak();
}
```

When I try to compile this I get warnings about 'method hiding' which I'm pretty sure I do not want to do. Trying to insert 'override' and 'virtual' keywords in front of the methods produced errors rather than warnings. Is there any way I can get a different description to show up for the method on a sub-interface without breaking the inheritance between the types?

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary if your interface is properly defined. That a `Dog` speaks by barking and a `Duck` speaks by quacking is the kind of thing that is covered by an implementation, not an interface. The interface description of the base should be applicable to all derived interfaces, otherwise you're changing the semantics of the operation (which should mean introducing a new one instead).

Comment: I had a feeling people would say this, in my case the description of the base interface does apply to the child interfaces, but it's very abstract. I want the child interface description to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "no". In C#, you can't modify a derived method unless you override it, and since you can't override an interface method, any new declaration in a derived interface will just shadow the original one.

A derived interface is really just tacking on more methods, it can't change, augment or tweak the base definition in any way, including XML comments -- there's just no place to put those. It is possible if you use abstract base classes instead, of course, but even then only artificially, by "overriding" the abstract method to simply call the base.

Comment: I guess this is my answer then, I'm pretty sure I can tweak the output of the tool I'm using to translate the xml into web pages to show whatever I want, but the code itself will probably have to stay as is.

Comment: @Ghost314: in that vein, there's one loophole I haven't covered. Although you cannot override the method in C#, what an XML comment *does* is simply produce an entry in the accompanying XML file. Tools that interpret these comments may or may not do the right thing if you manually insert the documentation for the "new" methods. If you want to get really fancy, you can do this by applying a custom attribute to the class (`XmlDocOverride("speak", ...)`) and post-processing the results. Might be overkill, but there's no kill like overkill.